# How to "Custom Post Type" as a non-programmer?

Tags: custom-post-types

I need to create a Wordpress Custorm Post Type with the following fields, I am not a developer and would appreciate a cut and paste. The Fields are:

Contact Person, Address, Telephone, Cellphone, Fax, Email, Website

HELP

Comment: ...or try [WordPress Custom Post Type Code Generator](http://themergency.com/generators/wordpress-custom-post-types/)

Comment: "majoring in wordpress development, graphic design for web and print" -http://zealmurapa.com/

Answer (score 3):

I think you have misunderstood what Custom Post Types are used for, if your trying to gather data try a plugin called Contact-Form-7 or if you want to post data then try using custom fields with the name of Contact Person, Address, Telephone, Cellphone, Fax, Email, Website.

You can echo custom fields into your theme files with the following code:

```
<?php $custom_field = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom-field-name', $single = true); ?>
<?php echo $custom_field  ?>
```

if you add a custom field called: 'contact-name'
then you can setup the code to echo the data as follows;

```
<?php $contact_name = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'contact-name', $single = true); ?>
    <?php echo $contact_name ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Xavier, I understand the custom field format, but I want to register and display a new 'custom post type' and call it Organization, which will have posts with the above mentioned values (i.e. Contact Person, Address, Telephone, Cellphone, Fax, Email, Website.) and the title, content and featured image. Hope I have better explained myself, can you help?

Comment: Why do you need a custom post type?  If you are a newbie to coding and wordpress i wouldn't recommend using Custom Post Types at all as they are much harder to work with, just add a category under Posts and name it "Organisations" then to all posts under "Organisations" just add custom fields to those posts

All you have to do from there is query a category to display the data.

Comment: Also your website states the following **majoring in wordpress development, graphic design for web and print**

So i have agree with @Roman Wünsche if you want someone to provide you the "majoring" that your website claims then pay a fee for it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for non developers to create custom post types is to use the [Custom Post Type UI plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/).

That said, I don't think custom post types are what you really want, do you really want to show Person, Address, etc on separate pages? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add the custom post type in a plugin file, like this

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );


function create_post_type() {

register_post_type('file', array(
    'label' => __('Organizations'), // e.g. apples
    'singular_label' => __('Organization'), // e.g. apple
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, // UI in admin panel
    '_builtin' => false, // It's a custom post type, not built in!
    '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d',
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array("slug" => "YOURNAME"), // Permalinks format
    'supports' => array('title','author','custom-fields','comments' )
));
```

}

See for full possible options this page [register post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Then to add each field to the post type, you could use post meta.

```
add_post_meta($post_id, YOURMETANAME, YOURVALUE);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'Name', 'John Doe');
```

which you can retrieve with:

```
get_post_meta($post_id, YOURMETANAME, YOURVALUE);
get_post_meta($post_id, 'Name', 'John Doe');
```

This can't be done with simple copy/pasting, it will require some work from your side...

Comment: Thanks Jan, I managed to register the custom post, now I need the meta data for it, what's the next step, thanks for spoon feeding me.

Comment: @Zeal: Don't get me wrong, but do you really expect that someone code the whole project for you? JanWillem give you some examples and suggestions. If you aren't a programmer, ask someone and pay a small fee for a solution.

Comment: Your usage of `__()` is pointless: WordPress doesn’t have the string `'Organizations'` in its default language file.

Comment: @Zeal see also [metabox](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metabox) tag